# Git with a workspace for each different branch

Tags: git, version-control, branch

What I am wanting to do is to setup a remote server to mantain code with git. I would want to generate a different workspace on every branch (including master) in order to serve the different versions at the same time. Why? I am configuring git server in a local web server with the tests purpose before upload the web pages to production environments, and when a developer needs to modify the code I would want to generate a branch for this development with his own workspace. With this way I can access the stable version in every computer of the LAN and the upcoming versions of the developers running. Is that possible with git or do I have to change the versioning software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean that you want to checkout a working directory (what you call "workspace") of each current branch on your webserver, so people (developers, testers) can easily and quickly access your application in the state of each branch.

This is easily possible: `git branch --no-merged master` will give you all "open" branches, i.e., branches that have not been merged back into `master`. You can also filter on branch name with `git branch --list --no-merged master FEATURE-*` would give you all non-merged branches starting with "FEATURE-".

From there on, if you are on Unix:

```
cd somecurrentworkingdirectory 
for branch in `git branch --no-merged master` ; do
   echo Creating $branch
   git clone git://source/repos/xyz /whereveryourwebserveris/branches/$branch -b $branch
   ... do more stuff to get it working on your webserver ...
done
```

Or similar if you are on Windows and using some other script language.

Also, there are existing solutions for that, for example Jenkins ("continuous integration", "continuous deployment").

Comment: I will check Jenkins, maybe this is the solutions I am looking for. Thanks a lot! +1

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible but it does not make sense.
With git since you don't git push, all the changes are limited to your local repositories i.e. if you do git commit, you save changes locally.
So you could modify every branch, then commit your changes and if are correct you could push to the remote server, otherwise you could do restore the previous versions of the file.

Comment: Of course, I was thinking on the server configuration, not the local git working. When the developer do a git push to the correct branch I could access the code via browser to every branch and master.